# Чередование вывода цикла 2 через 2

Tags: php

Как вывести цикл с чередованием 2 через 2 например Р-рабочий и В-выходной:

> РРВВРРВВРРВВ...

То есть это таблица посменного графика работы сотрудников 2х2.
Мне важно условие понять и правильно применить.
Вот например есть что то вроде этого:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3) {
        echo "<td>Р</td>";
    } else { 
        echo "<td>В</td>";
    }
}
```

Но он выводит `РРВРРВРРВРР` а надо `РРВВРРВВРРВВРР` и т.д.

Может есть условие наподобие этого?
Пояснение:
В идеале должна выводиться вот такая таблица http://shot.qip.ru/00Mw9C-6hBxM64Eb/ где Р-рабочий день и В-выходной день (вот эту строку для каждого работника я и не могу вывести). После чего идет еще условие ЕСЛИ пользователь при составлении графика указал какой либо день для данного сотрудника (на примере Иванова) как выходной (отпросился например) то ячейка закрашивается желтым цветом. То есть условия в условиях. Надуюсь понятно))

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать? что именно не получилось?

Comment: Вот например есть что то вроде этого:
`for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) { // Вывод ячеек
               
               if ($i % 3)....`
Но он выводит РРВРРВРРВРР что есть не совсем то что надо.
Условие наподобие этого может есть?

Comment: Вам стоит во-первых добавить код в сам вопрос, а во-вторых конкретизировать проблему.

Comment: если сотрудники в массиве (индекс с 0), то индекс текущего сотрудника можно рассчитать как `(i div dayCount) mod staffCount`, где i - рассматриваемый день, dayCount - количество рабочих дней сотрудника, а staffCount - число сотрудников. `div` - деление без остатка, а `mod - остаток от деления

Comment: Вот тут совсем не понятно. Мне сотрудники пока не нужны

Comment: ааа, Р - это рабочий, а В - выходной? ну тогда считайте, что `staffCount` равен 2 и `dayCount` равно 2. Сейчас формулу для произвольных рабочих и выходных приведу

Comment: Ага, именно так. Р-рабочий и В-выходной. График работы 2 через 2. Прошу прощения что запутал.

Comment: смотрите `(i mod (workday + holiday)) div workday` и если больше чем 0, значит сейчас выходной ), либо смотрите `i mod (workday + holiday)` и если больше workday, значит выходной

Comment: `for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i +=2)  echo "PPBB" ;` :)

Comment: @splash58, тогда уж `+4` )

Comment: можно просто отрезать нужный кусок `echo substr(str_pad('', 32, 'PPBB'), 0, 31);`

Comment: @BOPOH, ну да - заработался :)

Comment: Я почему на `IF` делаю? Потому что потом в них `if` будут еще условия. Поэтому  `echo substr(str_pad('', 32, 'PPBB'), 0, 31);` и `for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i +=2) echo "PPBB" ;` не совсем подходят. К тому же будет HTML меняться согласно условиям.
К слову в переменной $days целое число 29 (количество дней в месяце февраль).

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, ваша задача сводится к разбиению последовательности чисел на группы по 2. Для проверки, к какой группе относится то или иное число можно использовать вот такую функцию:

```
function isWorkDay($num) {
    return ($num % 4) < 2;
};
```

В контексте вашей задачи, цикл может выглядеть вот так:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    echo(sprintf('<td>%s</td>', isWorkDay($i) ? 'Р' : 'В'));
}
```

**UPD:**

Если очень хочется, можно использовать конструкцию `if - else`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    if (isWorkDay($i)) {
        echo('<td>Р</td>');
    } else {
        echo('<td>В</td>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Почти то что надо! Только в начале скрипт выводит РВВРРВВ... А надо чтоб РРВВРРВВ... Если вместо `$i = 1;` поставить `$i = 0;` то нормально. У меня переменная $days отдает число (количество дней в месяце). Хотя в принципе наверное не имеет значения чему равна $i. Попробую ваш вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил, подправил условие в цикле

Comment: Все прекрасно но:
Если поставить `$i = 0;` и вместо $days цифру 29 (дней в феврале) то первые РР выводит две шт. как надо. Зато всего 30 символов вообще. А надо 29. И как мне потом в этот код добавить какое либо условие если потребуется?

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Обратите внимание на знак в условии цикла `$i < $days`. Тут `<` вместо вашего `<=`

Comment: @Михаил, proof: https://ideone.com/zULPh7

Comment: Все отлично работает. Вот только Дмитрий, не понятно как теперь условия туда прописывать (в вопросе пояснил про желтый цвет)?

Comment: @Михаил, преобразуйте `?:` в нормальный `if` и дополнительно проверяйте счетчик массива на "критерий желтого цвета" =)

Comment: Так это ?: if else? Тогда все понятно. Это ведь сокращение?

Comment: Разве можно в sprintf() писать что либо кроме их условий и параметров? Я все же много не знаю про PHP.

Comment: Так вам же не обязательно использовать `sprintf` =)

Comment: Вы меня простите, Дмитрий. Но я никак не пойму как преобразовать Ваше условие в условие `IF ELSE`. Вы пишете дополнительно проверять счетчик массива на "критерий желтого цвета". Как?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Проверка на "желтый цвет" делается еще одним условием в цикле и соответствующей правкой вывода. Думаю вам стоит потратить немного времени и разобраться с тем, как работает PHP.

Comment: Мда... Перечитал свой комментарий и понял что фигню написал. Прошу прощения. Я построил условие IF но оно все равно выводит РВВРРВВ... А надо чтоб РРВВРРВВ.... Если поменять $i=0 то появляется лишний столбец. https://ideone.com/OJKP9p

Comment: @Михаил, кроме `$i = 0`, нужно `$i < $days` (**без равенства**). И все будет хорошо. Я же вам на это уже указывал выше

Comment: Пробовал и вот что получается http://shot.qip.ru/00Mw9C-6hBxM64HN/
Дело в том что далее идет сравнение числа месяца с выходными и  таблица съезжает потому как если указать $i=0 то отсчет будет с 0 а числа месяца сравниваются с 1 до 31 например.

Comment: Или может я вообще не потому пути пошел((( Может тут что подскажите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500687/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-php ?

Answer (score 0):

А я люблю биты (не бейсбольные). Смотрите, как выглядят числа от 0 до 3 в двоичной системе:

```
0  00
1  01
2  10
3  11
```

Заметили – левый бит как раз чередуется с шагом в 2 – почти то, что нужно. Выражение `$i & 2` будет равно либо 0, либо 2 – в зависимости от этого бита. `2` в двоичной системе `10`, а битовый оператор `&` оставляет «включёнными» только те биты, что включены в обоих операндах.

Надо ещё скорректировать, с чего начинать месяц. Дата всегда 1-е, но, если предыдущий месяц закончился, например, на двух "Р" подряд, начинать и этот опять с двух "Р" кому-то покажется несправедливым: четыре "Р" подряд!

Итого, я бы [сделал](http://ideone.com/C0LwK6) так:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
    if (($i+1) & 2) { // Выражение перед &: 0,1,2,3 -> В,В,Р,Р
        echo "<td>Р</td>";
    } else { 
        echo "<td>В</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо огромное! И да Вы правы по поводу с чего начинать месяц. Для этого я думаю будет использоваться переменная с первым рабочим днем месяца для каждого сотрудника ну и далее опять условия и т.д.

Comment: Вроде все сделал. Только вот осталось придумать как начать выводить РР с нужного дня. Для каждого сотрудника есть первый рабочий день месяца (число 01,03,07 и т.д.). Подскажите пожалуйста как можно использовать условие в вашем цикле на проверку этого дня?

Comment: Пусть первый рабочий день `$start`. Вместо `$i+1` пишите `$i - $start + 2`: начинает с 7-го, пишите `$i -7 +2`

Comment: Если честно, то никак не получается. Может поможете? Я не прошу за меня сделать просто подтолкните меня https://ideone.com/yNtzzt
Если меняю как вы сказали, то получается вот что http://shot.qip.ru/00Mw9C-6hBxM64Io/ все первые рабочие дни получаются РВВРРВВ

Comment: До первого рабочего дня вы хотите просто пустую ячейку? Тогда добавьте условие `if( $i < $start){ /*пустая ячейка*/ } else { /*здесь вся та магия с ($i-$start+2) & 2 */}`

Comment: [Добавил строки](https://ideone.com/cms5lw) с 10 по 13.

Comment: Сработало! Огромное, человеческое спасибо! Только если не указать первый рабочий день то у тех у кого он не указан начало РВВРРВВ... Ну да ладно сделаю это поле обязательным)) Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: если $start пустой, делайте его 1:  `if( !$start) $start = 1;`